Copied InDesign file links to original source files, not to the packaged links
I'm freelancing and downloaded an existing, packaged InDesign file from the client's server. I opened the INDD and did a save-as in a new folder on my computer; everything still linked to the packaged folder I'd downloaded on my desktop.
When I was done editing, I packaged my renamed file to my desktop, and this packaged INDD linked to the new packaged links folder, as it should. All normal.
Then I copied just my INDD from the new packaged folder to a new location on my hard drive to make an alt version. Rather than linking to my new packaged folder, or even to the original packaged folder I'd downloaded, the INDD link paths all reverted to random locations on the client server.
It's easy enough to relink everything to my desktop folder, but does anyone know why this happened? I don't want old or modified links on a server worming their way into my files if I don't notice the paths changing.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. A guess would be that when you copied the file to a different location, this is where you went astray. Basically, copying the file broke the links. Instead of copying it, open it in InDesign, save to a new location with a new file name, then make your alterations, save it. Then create a new package. It's difficult to say for sure however without access to your files, so I'm not adding this as an answer. It's just a guess.

I don't know how this is solvable without access to your specific work environment. I've never encountered the mis-linking you are referring to.

Billy, thanks for the suggestion, but what you suggest is exactly what I did: open downloaded file, save-as to new folder/name, edit & repackage. Then copy that new, packaged INDD to another new folder/name, and that's the one with the links problem. It's so odd.

Difficult to figure out what you're doing, so only one way to make sure:

create a new folder and give it a random name, lets say "ABCD"
create a folder inside "ABCD" and name this one "Links"
move all the linked files to the "Links" folder
move your INDD file to the "ABCD" folder
(optional at this point, disconnect from network so ID is unable to access any cloud files or whatever you may have there)
open the INDD, and you will probably get missing links messages
relink one of the pictures and look out for the option to check for missing links in the same folder, in which case ID will normally relink everything from "..\ABCD\Links"
use Preflight or the Links panel to figure out if you still have any missing links
when they're all re-linked, re-save the INDD file on top of itself (overwrite)



Thanks, lmlmlm. I'll see if manually moving links makes a difference. It could be a fun, extra step to add to my process! :) I've been using InDesign for 20+ years and working on remote servers since 2018, and this is a mystery.

Could also try to export IDML just for a test, its a more basic format and might reduce some of the noise in your INDD file. Also unwire any network connection, to make sure the links are to be looked up locally.

Good idea to try the IDML. And I'm usually only connected to the server when I have to transfer files, so I'll be more diligent in logging off before working on anything. Thanks for the suggestions.
